# Session gets emptied on making payment

Tags: php, session, zen-cart

I am working on zen cart.There is a peculiar problem I am facing here.Whenever the user logs in a session is created.Now when the user goes to the shopping cart,adds items to the cart and confirms the order everything is working fine.But as soon as the user makes payment certain of the session data like customer_id,customer_type,customer_name,etc gets blank,though the session is not destroyed because the user is not getting logged out.I can't figure what exactly the problem is.`Session_start()` is obviously defined on the top of the page.There isnt any domain name problem.Also this code is working perfectly in the `localhost`.

### Code of previous page of payment page

```
<?php
if(strpos(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR,'2')===0) {
?>
<div class="breadCrumb"><?php echo $breadcrumb->trail(BREAD_CRUMBS_SEPARATOR); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<h1 id="checkoutPaymentHeading"><?php echo HEADING_TITLE; ?></h1>
<?php echo zen_draw_separator(OTHER_IMAGE_SILVER_SEPARATOR, '100%', '1'); ?>
<?php
$class =& $_SESSION['payment'];
?>
<fieldset id="csNotifications">
<legend><?php echo NAVBAR_TITLE_2; ?></legend>
<p class="main" ><?php echo TEXT_ISECURE_PAYMENT; ?></p>
<div class="main" >
    <?php echo zen_draw_separator(OTHER_IMAGE_SILVER_SEPARATOR, '100%', '1'); ?><br/>
    <?php echo TITLE_CONTINUE_CHECKOUT_PROCEDURE . '&nbsp;' . TEXT_CONTINUE_CHECKOUT_PROCEDURE; ?><br/>
</div>
<table style="width:100%;" class="main" >
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right" class="main">
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['payment']->form_action_url)) {
    $form_action_url = $_SESSION['payment']->form_action_url;
  } else {
    $form_action_url = zen_href_link('https://direct.tranzila.com/xmobile/', '', 'SSL');
  }
  $return_url =  zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PROCESS, 'referer=tranzila', 'SSL');
  echo zen_draw_form('checkout_confirmation', 'https://direct.tranzila.com/xmobile/', 'post');  
  echo 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('currency', '2') . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('sum', $_SESSION['cart']->total) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('TranzilaToken', $_SESSION['securityToken']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('supplier', 'xmobile') . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('myid', '0000000'.$_SESSION['customer_id']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('contact', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxName']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('email', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxEmail']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('phone', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxPhone']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('cancel_return', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT, '', 'SSL')). "\n" .
  zen_draw_hidden_field('MerchantNumber', $_SESSION['is_info']['MerchantNumber']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('language', $_SESSION['is_info']['language']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxName', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxName']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxAddress', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxAddress']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxCity', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxCity']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxProvince', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxProvince']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxPostal', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxPostal']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxCountry', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxCountry']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxEmail',  $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxEmail']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxVar1', $_SESSION['is_info']['is_order_id']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxVar2', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxVar2']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('xxxPhone', $_SESSION['is_info']['xxxPhone']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('Products', $_SESSION['is_info']['Products']) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('ReturnURL', $return_url) . "\n" . 
  zen_draw_hidden_field('cancel_return', zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT, '', 'SSL')) ;

  echo zen_image_submit(BUTTON_IMAGE_CONTINUE, BUTTON_CONTINUE_ALT) . '</form>' . "\n";
?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

### Code of payment page

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['Response'] == '000')
{
$zco_notifier->notify('NOTIFY_HEADER_START_CHECKOUT_PROCESS');
    require(DIR_WS_MODULES . zen_get_module_directory('checkout_process.php'));
$_SESSION['cart']->reset(true);
unset($_SESSION['sendto']);
    unset($_SESSION['billto']);
    unset($_SESSION['shipping']);
    unset($_SESSION['payment']);
    unset($_SESSION['comments']);
    $order_total_modules->clear_posts();
$zco_notifier->notify('NOTIFY_HEADER_END_CHECKOUT_PROCESS');
    zen_redirect(zen_href_link(FILENAME_CHECKOUT_SUCCESS, (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'confirm' ? 'action=confirm' : ''), 'SSL'));
}
else
{
    zen_redirect(zen_href_link(FILENAME_PAYMENT_FAIL, (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'confirm' ? 'action=confirm&code='.$_REQUEST['Response'] : '&code='.$_REQUEST['Response']), 'SSL'));
    exit;
}
require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php');
```

Also is it really the session misbehaving or something else that is causing this bug?
And I forgot to mention that sessions are stored in the database.

Comment: Perhaps because you're unsetting everything?

Comment: I echoed 'print_r($_SESSION);' before the if condition to check what values I am getting and after that I have posted this question.So its not about that unsetting stuff.

Comment: are the session vars getting reset after payment page is posted, or after the confirm page (when checkout_process runs)? (what payment module are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration->Sessions

Check your settings, especially:

Recreate Session (set to false)

Try playing with your settings, to see how it effects your session status.